# color variable in animation doesn't work

Tags: jquery, css, animation

I don't see it. I want to change the color of a button by animation. The first click works the second not. I checked the var c and it gets a rgb color correctly but evidently don't give it correctly to the animation.

```
  var grey2 = "#555";
  $(".mainMenu .fa-search").click(function() {
    var c = $( this ).css("color");
    if ( i == 0) {
      $(".mainMenu .searchForm").slideDown();
      $( this ).animate({color: grey2});
      i = 1;
    } else {
      $(".mainMenu .searchForm").slideUp();
      $( this ).animate({color: c});
      i = 0
    };
```

Comment: You need to include jQuery UI in order to animate this property.

Comment: I use gsap. The color animation is not the problem.

Comment: var = grey2 = "#555"; -> var grey2 = "#555"

Comment: you're right, was a mistake here, but not in my code. It still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When second time you click it change color to grey2(#555) so var c has #555 so both are equal.
that's why second time it is not working
Try this code

```
var grey2 = "#555";
var c =  $(".mainMenu .fa-search").css("color");
$(".mainMenu .fa-search").click(function() {
    if ( i == 0) {
        $(".mainMenu .searchForm").slideDown();
        $( this ).animate({color: grey2});
        i = 1;
    } else {
        $(".mainMenu .searchForm").slideUp();
        $( this ).animate({color: c});
        i = 0
    };
});
```